# Why would Wilf Mott be shooting moles?

Tags: doctor-who

[Bernard Cribbins made his last appearance, at the age of ninety three, in "Wild Blue Yonder" the second episode of a Dr Who three-parter](https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/sci-fi/doctor-who-wilfred-mott-passing-bernard-cribbins-newsupdate/).  His character was to have been part of episode three; "The Giggle", but Bernard died before filming of that episode began so his character only 'appeared' off-screen.

[image]

Bernard Cribbins was one of the great actors of British TV and cinema, from the late 1950s to 2022.  He appeared in so many TV programmes, films, radio series, he was a ubiquitous part of the background to our lives through those years, playing everything from an astronaut to a Womble.  His first appearance in Dr Who was as Tom Campbell in the feature film Daleks' Invasion Earth 2150 in 1966, and returned as Wilf Mott from 2007 to 2022.

At the end of "The Giggle", the main characters are sitting around a table in the garden sans Wilf.  "He's off shooting moles," said Sylvia, explaining Wilf's absence. The Doctor noted that the moles were safe, however, having given them force fields.

Shooting moles seems to be a bit out of character for Wilf, is this a reference that I'm missing?  I can't find anything in Bernard Cribbins' filmography that might explain it.

Also, who has moles in their garden in Chiswick???

Comment: https://pestcontrol.co.uk/area/W/Chiswick/mole-removal.php

Comment: I suppose it's a bit of a stretch to imagine it's because he read [Wind in the Willows](https://www.bbc.co.uk/teach/school-radio/english-ks2-the-wind-in-the-willows-index/znngf4j) [He also played Ratty in a 60's version]

Comment: As the old saying goes, never bring a mole to a knife fight.

Comment: [SPOILER] A side issue: the novelization reveals that this scene takes place at a house the Doctor has purchased with his decades of accumulated UNIT salary, not at Donna's house, so it's not necessarily in Chiswick.

Comment: *And they all looked up – there at the end of the lawn, went
Wilfred Mott in his wheelchair, whizzing past, holding an ancient
shotgun made in Birmingham. His excited cries drifted over to them.
‘I’ll get ’em! Don’t you worry, Doctor. You stay there! I’ll get the little
…’
‘Leave them alone!’ Rose called.*

Comment: Jasper Carrott explains.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tntoPH-QFU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bernard Cribbins (Wilf) died during filming, after the scenes with him visiting the TARDIS but before this final scene was filmed. The makers toyed with the idea of having him canonically die to explain his absence from the dinner scene, but in the end they decided to [put him on the metaphorical bus](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PutOnABus).

> **Russell Davis:** *He actually died during the filming of this. And I actually wrote a version of this scene in which you discussed his passing. It was beautiful and it was very much a reaction to what had literally just happened because it felt very, very strange, and so I felt like we had to acknowledge it and it was, you can imagine how tonally it fits in with this, remembering the past and coming to terms with those we've lost and stuff like that.*
>
> *And then Phil, my learned friend Phil Collinson just went, "Are you mad? Are you mad?" and of course he's alive off-camera. And of course he's alive forever just around the corner and I just went "You're so right" ... Now Bernard's forever, shooting moles over the fence"*
>
> <sub><sup>[Doctor Who: The Giggle - Audio Commentary](https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/p0gsdjvn/doctor-who-video-commentaries-the-giggle-with-commentary)</sup></sub>

Obviously they needed a way for him to be too far away to be seen, but close enough to be heard, hence the shotgun. And if he's firing a shotgun, he needs to be firing it *at* something.

---

As to why he hates moles, it's noteworthy that Wilf maintained [an allotment](http://www.david-tennant.co.uk/2013/10/tenth-doctor-month-meet-companions_9.html) for very many years (seen briefly in [*Turn Left*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPuIs.png)). It's very likely that he's now growing his veg in the large garden at the rear of the new house and wants the garden to be mole-free.

Comment: I think the allotment is the key to this.  Wilf could well have, over the years, been trying to keep his fruit and veg safe from the upheavals of moles.

Answer (score -1):

When moles dig tunnels, they put the soil they remove to do so in a heap on the ground surface called a molehill.  Sometimes, people who keep lawns think these molehills spoil the look of the lawn.  It's actually really easy just to rake the heaps of soil away, leaving humans and moles alike happy; but some people prefer a violent solution like shooting the moles.

Comment: They make a big fuss about them...

Comment: @Valorum Alpine in scale.

Comment: Unfortunately the 'gamekeeper's gibbet' is still a thing on the grouse moors of England (there were a couple of dozen moles on the last one I saw), supposedly because moles interfere with the grouse and pheasant.